Spring Data JPA Custom Update Query Not Updating Entity in Database
I'm encountering an issue with an update query in my Spring Data JPA repository. The query isn't updating the database as expected. Here are the details:
Repository Query
The query in my repository is defined as follows:
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Transactional
@Query("UPDATE JobMeta j SET j.document_id = :document_id, j.status = :status WHERE j.id = :id")
int updateDocumentIdAndStatus(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("document_id") String documentId,
                              @Param("status") String status);

Service Method
This is how I am using the above repository method in my service:
public void updateJobStatus(final DmsCallbackRequest request) {
    final Long jobId = Long.valueOf(request.getJobId());
    logger.info("spider : Updating the Job Status after DMS Callback: {} {}", request.getJobId(), request.getZipDocumentId());

    final Optional<JobMeta> optionalJobMeta = this.jobMetaRepository.findById(jobId);
    try {
        if (optionalJobMeta.isPresent()) {
            logger.info("spider : ZipDocumentId received from request: {} {}", request.getJobId(), request.getZipDocumentId());
            int count = this.jobMetaRepository.updateDocumentIdAndStatus(jobId,
                    request.getZipDocumentId(), States.zip_success.name());
            logger.info("spider : JobMeta Rows Updated: {}", count);
        } else {
            logger.warn("spider : JobMeta not found for JobId: {}", request.getJobId());
            throw new JobMetaNotFoundException("JobMeta not found for JobId: " + request.getJobId());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error updating job status to 'success' for JobMeta Id: {} {}", jobId, e.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException("Error updating job status to 'success'", e);
    }
}


What I've Tried
I have tried two approaches to update the document_id:
Directly Updating the Entity:
if (optionalJobMeta.isPresent()) {
    logger.info("spider : ZipDocumentId received from request: {} {}", request.getJobId(), request.getZipDocumentId());
    JobMeta meta = optionalJobMeta.get();
    meta.setDocument_id(request.getZipDocumentId());
    meta.setStatus(States.zip_success.name());
    jobMetaRepository.save(meta);
    logger.info("spider : JobMeta Rows Updated");
}


Using the Custom Update Query:
int count = this.jobMetaRepository.updateDocumentIdAndStatus(jobId,
        request.getZipDocumentId(), States.zip_success.name());


Following is JobMeta Class for reference
package com.sh.spider.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.cglib.core.Local;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "job_meta")
public class JobMeta implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Set<JobDetail> jobDetails = new HashSet<>();
    private int total_links;
    private int success_links;
    private int failed_links;
    private String document_id;
    private String user_identifier;
    private String status;
    private LocalDateTime created_on;
    private String zip_url;
    private LocalDateTime zip_expired_on;
}


Problem
In both the approaches doesn't seem to update the document_id in the database, although it executes without throwing exceptions.
Question
Why isn't the custom update query working as expected? Are there any additional configurations or adjustments I need to make for it to work properly?

It would be useful to see the JobMeta Class, can you post this. To get more diagnostic information you could try enabling sql logging, e.g spring.jpa.show-sql=true spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

@0xadecimal I've added JobMeta class for reference. I enabled sql Logging and I can see the sql query is getting executed

ok - try removing the clearAutomatically = true from the @Modifying annotation and retest.  Can you confirm how you are checking the update - are you running a native query against the DB or are you checking via a spring data query?

Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78989968/spring-data-jpa-custom-update-query-not-updating-entity-in-database

How do you check that the update didn't work? Where are your transaction boundaries? Has your code left those before you check if the update worked?
